# Compatible Finite Elements

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, definitions, finite-element-method

I have a basic question as a matter of definition. I am wondering what is meant by compatible finite elements? Does it has to do with the spaces over which the trial functions are defined?

Comment: Hi, Welcom to MO. I think it'd be easier to answer if you refer us, or even better quote, the place where you've seen this definition.